# Add extra fields to Add New Category page

Tags: categories, custom-field

I need to add an extra field to the Add New Category page. Currently it only has fields for Name, Slug, and Description. Essentially, I need to have a second description text box.

I use the current Description field at the bottom of each category page, but now I need to have additional information specific to the category (and different from the bottom) displayed at the top.

How can I add this additional field?

Below is what I am trying to achieve:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/QLNC6.jpg]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ended up solving this with bainternet's plugin at http://en.bainternet.info/2012/wordpress-taxonomies-extra-fields-the-easy-way

Answer (score 4):

If you want a plugin solution, [advanced custom fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) can do this.